# Could someone create these tags?

Tags: support, tags

Could someone create tags for `roberts-rules` and `parliamentary-procedure` possibly `parliamentary-rules`?

Specifically referring to this question: [Appointment and Elected Offices of an Assembly under Robert's Rules](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3614/appointment-and-elected-offices-of-an-assembly-under-roberts-rules)

Comment: More info about tag creation on the network meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146950/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't create tags in isolation - they need to be applied to a question. If there is a question you would like these applied to, please edit the question to add them, or include them when asking.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Yeah, so is there something preventing you from adding those tags to that question? You have the reputation and privileges to do so.

Comment: I read that you needed 1500 rep to create tags.

Comment: 150 reputation is required to create tags, and 300 on graduated sites. If you are experiencing difficulty creating a tag, please post it as a [meta-tag:bug] and include the steps to reproduce it. Thanks.

Comment: It was a problem with the mobile version. Worked in the browser.

Comment: @Viktor, it depends on the site, 1,5k is probably just on SO, here you only need 150 so far: http://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges.